# how to convert a CFG to c++ code

Tags: c++, c, context-free-grammar

I have a context free grammar (CFG). I want to write a c++ code to do the same thing like CFG.

Is there any built-in function or easy way to convert?
Or, something to execute CFG?

Comment: A CFG does nothing, it simply describes a structure. You want to build a parser that parses your CFG, right?

Comment: I need c++ code that will work like a parser under that CFG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [parser generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler) (sometimes called compiler-compilers). You already know about `bison`. You could try [ANTLR3](http://antlr3.org/) (or [ANTLR4](http://antlr.org/) for Java). Here is a [comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators).

BTW, most of the time programming languages are not really context free (e.g. because they need some [symbol table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table)).

Also, some parsers are hand written [recursive descent ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), (e.g. GCC, see [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/254707/40065))

Notice that a [context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) is a *specification* for some formal syntax (which you could *implement* in some parser). But [semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29) and [pragmatics](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) also matters.

Comment: ANTLR does not output C++ anymore. It used to in version 3, version 4 only does Java.

Comment: But the OP could use ANTLR3

Comment: Yes, but you linked the ANTLR4 website. ANTLR3 is [here](http://www.antlr3.org/). And using a discontinued version is not the best idea  when considering the future of your project.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at `bison`, the GNU implementation of `yacc`, which stands for `yet another compiler compiler`, and will generate a parser from the grammar you feed it with.

Comment: Actually I already do this using bison/yacc. Now I'm trying to implement this using c++

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Bison is written in C.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such C++ builtin, but you have a few alternatives.

1. parser generators: Flex+Bison allow you to generate a parser in C or C++ out of a description of your grammar, in (LA)LR or GLR form. If you have a good grasp on CFG, learning Bison syntax will be easy. Bison and Flex will output C code, but they can gracefully handle C++ in semantic actions.
2. top down parsers: if your grammar is in LL(k) form and you don't want to learn an extra langage, then you can easily derive a recursive descent parser from your grammar. This is quick, but LL is less powerful than (G)LR and mantaining a hand-written parser can quickly become a nightmare if you aren't super careful with all edge cases. LL parsers can be also implemented as table parsers (like LR are), but hand-editing the table is guaranteed to become a mess sooner or later.

Bison can also emit a C++ class instead of a function, just add:

```
%skeleton "lalr1.cc"
%language "c++"
%define parser_class_name {Parser}
```

to the prologue. The only difference is that now tokens are members of an enum and no more defines, so you have to use `Parser::token::TOKEN_NAME` instead of `TOKEN_NAME`.

Also Flex can be ehm... hammered... into producing a C++ class, but having Bison C++ and Flex C++ click together is not super straightforward and would be worth separate question.

Comment: So, If I want to write a code to implement CFG, I need to write lots of  "if-statement".. Nothing easy to do this?

Comment: @AerofoilKite it only works if your grammar is LL(k) (and deterministic). That is, at any given point, you can decide what to do based on the next `k` characters you read. So, yes, you read those `k` characters and select what function to call based on them. Called functions can perform the same. This is why it's called "recursive descent". Just google that, there is a ton of tutorials on the Internet.

Comment: To be honest, you could also implement a LALR parser by hand, but it will become really painful as soon as the language is no more trivial and each change to the grammar might result in a lot of subtle changes in the parsing table. Also, because of how they work, a wrong LALR parser is both super easy to get and super difficult to debug. Not to mention GLR.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to make a parser with `boost::spirit` - pure C++ solution, but requires dependency on Boost